# How to find the first value of linked list in a single linked list C++

Tags: c++, queue

```
int arrayQueue::takeAway() 
{
    char letter;
    if (empty())
    return -1;
    else {
    Data *p, info;
    if (top == NULL)
    {
            cout << "Error stack empty\n";
    } else {
        p = top;    //top is another Data struct instance
        info.value = p->value;  
        top = p->next;
        delete p;
        return info.value;
    }
}
}
```

For my data structures course we are creating a queue using pointers and linked lists, however I cannot figure out how to point to the FIRST value.  As the code is now, it points to the LAST value entered, which isn't useful in a queue setting.  I searched for other examples, but I can only find examples that use more than one linked list.  If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated!

edit: Here's how I am adding things to the queue

```
void arrayQueue::addToQueue(char x)  
    {
        if (full())
             cout << "Error, queue full \n";
         else {
             Data *p;
             p = new Data;
             p->value = x;
             p->next = top;
             top = p;
              }
    }
```

and this is my struct

```
struct Data
{
char value;
Data *next;
};
```

Comment: What is wrong on std::deque?

Comment: Can we see your code for the linked list? Typically a linked list has a pointer to the first node. Depending on how you are adding elements to the linked list, this could be the first node entered or the last node entered. If you are adding elements to the front of the list, than this pointer will be the most recent element. If you are adding elements to the back of the list than you will have the first element. You may need to keep a pointer to the back of the list.

Comment: Hopefully I added some relevant information!

Comment: Solved it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!

Comment: @user2793442 make sure to accept an answer that particularly helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement your linked list with head and tail pointers. This allows insert at the end -- `enqueue` and removal from the front `dequeue` to be done in constant time (O(1)). Here is a simple queue as a start:

```
template
class Queue {
  public:
    class Node {
      T val;
      Node* next;

      Node(const T& v) : val(v), next(NULL) {}
    }

    Queue() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), sz(0) {}

    void enqueue(const T& v) {
      Node* n = new Node(v);
      if(sz == 0) {
        head = tail = n;
      }
      else {
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
      }
      sz++;
    }

    T dequeue() {
      if(sz == 0) throw SomeException;

      Node* tmp = head;
      head = head->next;
      T v = tmp->val;
      delete tmp;
      sz--;
      return v;
    }

    const T& front() const {return tail->val;}
    size_t size() const {return sz;}
    bool empty() {return sz == 0;}

  private:
    Node* head, tail;
    size_t sz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your single-linked list should have two methods: 1)adding an element to the tail and 2) removing an element from the head. So your single linked-list class should support two pointers: one to the firts element of the list and other to the last element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have implemented your singly-linked-list as more of a stack (that is, it is FILO, first-in-last-out).  A queue is a FIFO (first in first out) structure.  To do that, you would need to let your singly-linked-list actually be a linked-list (that is, you can pop items off from either end) by adding a pointer to the head element (in addition to the tail pointer you already have), use a doubly-linked-list implementation, or keep your previous pointer in memory as you iterate through the list to get to the item that needs to be popped (e.g. what you are calling the tail).

Adding a head pointer will allow you to pop items off in constant time (`O(1)`), while changing your implementation to a doubly-linked-list (without a head pointer) will require linear time (`O(n)`).  Keeping the previous pointer in memory can also be done in linear time.